# Flex columns do not match

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two flex rows. First row has 6 equal columns with `flex: 1`. Second row has column with `flex: 4` and column with `flex:2`. Columns have `margin-right: 10px` set, except for last child in a row.

http://jsbin.com/gufihoyaha/edit?html,css,output

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row .col {
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: coral;
}

.row .col:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-4 {
  flex: 4;
}

.flex-2 {
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col flex-1">1</div>
  <div class="col flex-1">1</div>
  <div class="col flex-1">1</div>
  <div class="col flex-1">1</div>
  <div class="col flex-1">1</div>
  <div class="col flex-1">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col flex-4">4</div>
  <div class="col flex-2">2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the result differs from what I expected:

[image]

What I want is something like this:

[image]

Question:
**Why does it happen and how to fix that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `display:grid` would actually be able to do this correctly:

unfortunately, at this time, it is quiet new and not implemented every where. See http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

To know more about it : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.row .col {
  background-color: coral;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.row .col:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.flex-1 {}

.flex-4 {
  grid-column: auto / span 4;
}

.flex-2 {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col flex-1">1</div>
  <div class="col flex-1">1</div>
  <div class="col flex-1">1</div>
  <div class="col flex-1">1</div>
  <div class="col flex-1">1</div>
  <div class="col flex-1">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col flex-4">4</div>
  <div class="col flex-2">2</div>
</div>
```